# Creation of an avatar generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html, css

I'm about to create something [similar to this](http://platogo.com/avatars). That is, a cartoon character which should be possible to change in realtime by clicking on buttons.

My plan is to use javascript (jQuery) with HTML5 and CSS3, and integrate it with Django. What I would appreciate is some kind of advice on how to approach this task, e.g. which features / techniques / API's is could use. If you know about an Django app that could be useful for this task I would be really happy.

For example, is SVG suited for the task or should I use canvas?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Because you want it real-time I'd advise client-side processing. Given that 'flash is dead' (and not supported on apple iphoney stuff), I think canvas is a better solution (over SVG, that I find way to quircky).

One of the main advantages to canvas in this specific scenareo is that users can right-click the client-side (in canvas) generated image and save it just like any other image.

To get you started you might want to look at [tektek's dream avatar creator](http://www.tektek.org/dream/), this also uses canvas.